# Remove the click event from a single Div element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added a mousedown handler to all the divs inside a parent div, like this:

```
$productContainer.children(".button").on('mousedown', function(){
    var index = $(this).index();
    console.log("Clicked button at " + index);
    // this doesnt work
    $(this).removeAttr('mousedown');
});
```

Now I want to remove the mousedown handler after the button is clicked, for that particular div. How do I do that? Removing the `attr mousedown` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of :

```
$(this).removeAttr('mousedown');
```

use :

```
$(this).unbind('mousedown');
```

or

```
$(this).off('mousedown');
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `off` method:

```
$productContainer.children(".button").on('mousedown', function(){
    var index = $(this).index();
    console.log("Clicked button at " + index);
    $(this).off('mousedown');
});
```

More info: http://api.jquery.com/off/

You could also use the `one` method instead. It will automatically remove your event handler at the first time it is triggered:

```
$productContainer.children(".button").one('mousedown', function(){
    var index = $(this).index();
    console.log("Clicked button at " + index);
});
```

More info: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 1):

use [`.off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/)
    Description: Remove an event handler.

```
$productContainer.children(".button").off('mousedown');
$productContainer.children(".button").on('mousedown', function(){
    var index = $(this).index();
    console.log("Clicked button at " + index);
    // this doesnt work
    $(this).removeAttr('mousedown');
});
```